# FOSUserBundle override template not working on EC2

Tags: templates, symfony, amazon-ec2, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

Something very strange happening. I'm developing on OSX (`php 5.4.11` and the OSX built-in web server (not the PHP one). I've deploy my code on AWS EC2, fix the permissions with `setfacl` and run the site in dev mode (like on OSX).

On EC2 I'm running `php 5.4.12`. When I check the `config.php` it says that `Your configuration looks good to run Symfony`

The home page is loding perfectly but the registration page and login page are not loading the correct template (my user bundle is suppose to override those templates - and it's working on my local server).

The weirdest thing is that I've override the form type for the user registration and that I can see my additional fields. It's just twig that is not picking up the correct template.

There is nothing in the log files that can really help me (even in debug mode) and nothing in the error_log neither.

I don't know where to look to debug this because I have no idea at what point the template is suppose to be overwritten.

Any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: I've done a clean install of `centos 6.3` and `PHP 5.4.12` and I still have the exact same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might sound stupid, but MacOS has a case insensitive file system whereas on Linux it's case sensitive so, check the file names.

Comment: I love you man!! 6 to 8 hours over 2 days to debug this it was the `views` folder that was `Views`. I can't believe it !! Thank you so much !